# How can show 0 on group count using vars and intervals dynamics?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to **show 0 in a group count interval of months**

**TABLE:**

```
 |creations|
   |id|  |created_at|
     1    2014-01-11
     2    2014-01-21
     3    2014-01-12
     4    2014-02-22
     5    2014-02-13
     6    2014-03-12
     7    2014-03-23
```

**SHOULD HAVE THIS RESULT:**

```
    |counter|    |actual_year|    |actual_month|
        3            2014               1
        2            2014               2
        2            2014               3
        0            2014               4
```

I tried **IFNULL** but is not working:

```
SET @var_year = '2014';
SET @var_month = '1';

SET @from = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@var_year, '/', @var_month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d');
SET @to = DATE_ADD(@from, INTERVAL 4 MONTH);

SELECT IFNULL(count(created_at), 0),year(created_at) as actual_year,month(created_at)as actual_month FROM creations
WHERE created_at BETWEEN @from AND @to
GROUP BY month(created_at)
```

Also I tried **COALESCE**:

```
SET @var_year = '2014';
SET @var_month = '1';

SET @from = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@var_year, '/', @var_month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d');
SET @to = DATE_ADD(@from, INTERVAL 4 MONTH);

SELECT COALESCE(count(created_at), 0),year(created_at) as actual_year,month(created_at)as actual_month FROM creations
WHERE created_at BETWEEN @from AND @to
GROUP BY month(created_at)
```

Please somebody can help me?

Here is the [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06639/2)

**NOTE: @var_month, @var_year, INTERVAL are dynamic values**

Here is another [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34020/1) but here should be showing 0 in the month 7

```
    |counter|    |actual_year|    |actual_month|
        1            2014               5
        1            2014               6
        0            2014               7
        2            2014               8  
        1            2014               9
```

Here is the query:

```
SET @var_year = '2014';
SET @var_month = '5';

SET @from = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@var_year, '/', @var_month, '/01'), '%Y/%m/%d');
SET @to = DATE_ADD(@from, INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

SELECT COALESCE(count(created_at), 0),year(created_at) as actual_year,month(created_at)as actual_month FROM creations
WHERE created_at BETWEEN @from AND @to
GROUP BY month(created_at)
```

Comment: Do you want to stop at month four always?

Comment: No, just show 0 when is doesn't exist like my example..the interval could change.

Comment: The reason that `IFNULL(count(created_at), 0)` is not giving you a row showing actual_month=4 and counter=0 is that there are no rows where the month=4. So when you do `GROUP BY month(created_at)`, there is no group for that month upon which to count zero rows. The only ways I know of to display this type of thing in MySQL are complex, and it probably would be much more simple to handle it in the application that is calling the query and displaying its results.

Comment: I tried using COALESCE but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a simpler way to accomplish this, (and if someone can show it to us I would be very happy to see it) but the only way I can think of right now is to create a sort of fake table using UNION SELECT with the literal values you want to display, and join your query to that with an outer join. This can allow you to display the values for months which have no records in your database.

```
SELECT IFNULL(counter,0) as counter, literals.y AS actual_year, literals.m AS actual_month
FROM (
  SELECT @var_month AS m, @var_year + 0 AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 1) % 12, (@var_month + 1) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 1) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 2) % 12, (@var_month + 2) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 2) DIV 12) AS y
  UNION SELECT IF((@var_month + 3) % 12, (@var_month + 3) % 12, 12) AS m, @var_year + ((@var_month + 3) DIV 12) AS y)
  AS literals
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT count(*) as counter, year(created_at) y, month(created_at) as m 
 FROM creations WHERE created_at BETWEEN @from AND @to GROUP BY month(created_at)) AS counts
 ON literals.m = counts.m AND literals.y = counts.y;
```

This has some obvious limitations. It will only work for a four month interval unless you manually add more UNION SELECTS. I think it is overly complex for what it gives you. Unless you absolutely HAVE to do this in MySQL, I really think it would be easier to handle it with whatever application is using MySQL to request these results (assuming that is the case.)

Comment: Your code seems to be working just for this example but IF I CHANGE THE INTERVAL THIS WON'T WORK is there any other way? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06639/84

Comment: Well, I did say in the answer "It will only work for a four month interval," so I'm not sure what all your strident capitalization is about. As far as there being another way, there probably is, but I do not know it.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because you aren't getting a result set back because of your WHERE clause. There is literally nothing for it to Coalesce. The problem isn't that you are getting NULL. You are getting NOTHING.

You could get crafty with a UNION query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT count(created_at) as recordcount ,year(created_at) as actual_year,month(created_at)as actual_month 
        FROM creations
        WHERE created_at BETWEEN @from AND @to
        GROUP BY month(created_at)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 0, year(@from), month(@from)
    ) subquery
ORDER BY recordcount desc   
LIMIT 1
```

That's going to append a record to your existing query, then sort by `recordcount` and select only the highest record count. So if your original query returns NOTHING, then the UNIONED query will win as the `LIMIT 1` and return 0. If your query does return something, then it will win the `LIMIT 1` and be returned.

As @Don'tPanic noted above: This is pretty complicated just to get a resultset from the database that contains no useful data. Your probably better off handling this in the code that calls this sql statements (if there is code calling this sql statement) like in PHP or whatever you are rolling.

Comment: Sorry. MySQL syntax thing.. I changed the query above to use `LIMIT 1` instead of `TOP 1` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06639/45

Comment: Well your query shows 0 but is not the result that I want i want this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06639/58 showing at the same time like my question.

Comment: You select a specific month, but then how do get 3 or 4 returned? What is your logic here. Not the SQL logic to do it, but the laymans version: "When I give it January, I also want the next three months" or something like that...

Comment: Here for example VAR_YEAR, VAR_MONTH and INTERVAL are dynamic VALUES  so that's what I really want but it's so difficult http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d34020/1

Comment: I edited my question and added more info.please can you help me?